# Cleaning up the singular/plural tags

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Rather than creating a new post for every example we come across, let's try to keep them all here.  As they are changed/fixed, I'll try to keep a running tally here.  This way, if there are any issues or questions that pop up, we can discuss in one place :)

Comment: I'm good with that, we'd have a lot of posts otherwise :)

Comment: I don't get it. I'm tidying up microphone tags; I want to remove the `s` from `microphone-techniques` to keep the tags consistent. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I had a look at the list of tags using the Stack Exchange Data Explorer and used a regex expression to find all the tags using 's' as a suffix to find most of the plurals.

[director](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/director) and [directors](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directors)

[feature](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature) and [features](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/features)

[file](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file) and [files](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/files)

[fix](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fix) and [fixes](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixes)

[game](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) and [games](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games)

[gun](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gun) and [guns](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guns)

[headphone](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headphone) and [headphones](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headphones)

[horse](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horse) and [horses](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horses)

[instrument](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrument) and [instruments](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instruments)

[interview](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interview) and [interviews](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interviews)

[library](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/library) and [libraries](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/libraries)

[location](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/location) and [locations](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locations)

[mixer](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixer) and [mixers](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixers)

[monitor](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitor) and [monitors](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitors)

[outdoor](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outdoor) and [outdoors](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outdoors)

[plane](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plane) and [planes](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planes)

[rate](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rate) and [rates](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rates)

[recording](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recording) and [recordings](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recordings)

[reference](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference) and [references](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references)

[space](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space) and [spaces](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spaces)

[studio](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/studio) and [studios](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/studios)

[suggestion](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggestion) and [suggestions](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggestions)

[system](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system) and [systems](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/systems)

---

Also these tags are similar enough to be merged, or revised:

[edit](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edit) and [editing](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editing)

[emotion](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotion) [emotional-interpretation](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotional-interpretation) and [emotions](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotions)

[equalization](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equalization) and [equalizer](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equalizer)

[favorite](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/favorite) and [favourite](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/favourite)

[field-recorder](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-recorder) and [field-recording](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-recording)

[filter](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter) and [filtering](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filtering)

[plugin](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin), [plug-in](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plug-in) and [plug-ins](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plug-ins)

[soundeffects](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soundeffects), [sound-effects](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-effects) and [sound-effects-recording](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-effects-recording)

[web](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web) and [websites](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/websites)

There are probably many more missing, I honestly didn't expect to find so many results.

Many of these tags perhaps shouldn't exist or should have their scope revised.

Comment: A few of these actually have distinctions that are meaningful, but a lot of these are good to merge.  Thanks for digging in.

Answer (score 0):

[level](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/level) changed to [levels](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/levels)

Comment: I'll do these just a bit at a time so as not to flood the front page *too* bad :)

Answer (score 0):

[car](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/car) to [cars](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars), [vehicle](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle) to [vehicles](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicles)?