# Why do we still have a [sound-design] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tag-removal-request, tags

Why do we still have this tag? It is currently used by 782 questions but it adds nothing considering Sound Design is the name of the site.

Can we delete the tag and start re-tagging questions that only use that tag?

Comment: Is there a reason why this post has two conflicting status tags?

Comment: One part of the request was completed, the other was declined.

Comment: @AJHenderson In that case I will get rid of the second request so that it's clearer.

Comment: I have added more instances of the second request [here](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62/cleaning-up-the-singular-plural-tags/1390#1390).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I agree that sound-design isn't a useful tag.  It's more that the site is horribly named as we cover way WAY more than just sound design.  cable and cables should probably be merged though.

Cables has been merged with cable.  Sound-design will not be getting removed at this time as it provides meaningful categorization.

Comment: Well, it USED to be perfectly named but that another story…